# React Redirect not rendering Component

Tags: reactjs

I am currently learning React and right now I am trying to implement Redirect in React.
I have a file named logout.js which redirects the user to another file Mello.js. The redirect is successfull as the URL changes to `/Mello` in browser but the component for the same is not being rendered. My logout.js file is:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch,Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import Mello from './Mello';
class logout extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        isloggedout: false
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:3000/logout").
    then(res=>{this.setState({isloggedout:res.data.state})});
    console.log("hello from logout");
}
render(){
    return (
        this.state.isloggedout?<Router><Redirect to="/Mello" /></Router>:<p>Not allowed</p>
        );
}
}
export default logout;
```

Mello.js is:

```
import React from 'react';
class Mello extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
render(){
    console.log("Hello from Mello");
    return(<div>
        <h1>Hello from Mello</h1>
        </div>
        );
}
};

export default Mello;
```

The code by which I have set up all the routes:

```
<Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Hello} />
                <Route exact path="/Mello" component={Mello} />
                <Route exact path="/logout" component={logout} />
            </Switch>
</Router>
```

As the redirect happens, nothing is being printed on console(not even any error) and so is the case with h1 tag.
I would really appreciate any help. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<Redirect>` and `<Route>` are in separate Routers, so they're not linking up.

**All of them have to be in the same `<Router>` element.**

```
{this.state.isloggedout? <Router><Redirect to="/Mello" /><Switch> <Route exact path="/Mello" component={Mello} /></Switch></Router>}
```

(May not exactly be the best way to do it, but the fundamental issue is that both your `<Route>` and `<Redirect>` must fall under the same `<Router>`

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect

```
<Router>
<Switch>
  <Redirect from='/old-path' to='/new-path' />
  <Route path='/new-path'>
    <Place />
  </Route>
</Switch>
</Router>
```

Or

```
<Router>
<Route exact path="/">
  {loggedIn ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" /> : <PublicHomePage />}
</Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: No, I have already set it up in the same way as you have written. That is in another file named app.js

Comment: doesn't seem that way from your code - maybe update your code so we can see it

Comment: So, looks like you have 2 separate Routers. What happens if you place the <Switch></Switch> inside the <Router> with the <Redirect>?

Comment: <Router><Redirect to="/Mello" /><Switch>
  <Route path="/Mello" component={Mello} />
</Switch></Router>

Comment: It worked. But can you tell me how did you get this idea and why it is working?Even though I imported Mello but it wasn't working when I was trying

Comment: Yup, will update my answer now and you can mark it as correct if it makes sense

Comment: The answer you have written is little unclear and difficult to understand. Anyway, you solution worked!